# How to detect a linux port is bound by a process in Go?

Tags: linux, go

I am writing some e2e test in GO where a test ldap server is run via a Go routine. Then I run my tests via `t.Run()`. Sometimes tests fail because the server has not started yet. I have tried adding upto 10 secs of sleep before starting tests. But things are still flaky (especially on travis ci).

I could probably use ldap client to detect if the connect operation succeeds or not before calling `t.Run()` . But I am wondering if there is a more generic solution where a Go process can check if a port if already bound by some process. I am looking for something like `lsof` or `netstat` in Go.

I have searched online and found some solution where `net.Listen` is used to bind for that port and see if that succeeds or not. Obviously I don't want to do that since that will be fighting with my own code. Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `netstat` for this? Any performance issue?

Comment: Because parsing netstat output is not much fun. And not having to shell out to an external binary makes things more portable.

Comment: Well, you can skip the parsing. Just check the return code of your command: `netstat -anp | grep :<port>`. I totally agree with the "portability" part of your comment in case of "shell out".

Comment: The "generic" way to do this is by reading `/proc` directly. Honestly, running netstat is probably more portable, since it will already match your OS's specific version of `/proc`.

Comment: You could always just try connecting to it with `net.Dial`.